# Masking arbitrary square regions in batch in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a large 3D tensor in TensorFlow 2.0 with shape [batch_size, N, N]. Each sample in the batch contains a square ROI that I want to mask out (the sizes of the ROIs are defined in a separate array named inner_dims). I've been googling quite a lot but haven't been able to find a solution that appears efficient.

**Example:**

The example below shows what I want to accomplish. In this case, I have manually created a mask that does what I want:

```py
batch_size=5
N=4
# inputs.shape: [5, 4, 4]

inner_dims=[2, 3, 1, 4, 2]


mask=
[
 [
  [1 1 0 0]
  [1 1 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0]
 ]
 [
  [1 1 1 0]
  [1 1 1 0]
  [1 1 1 0]
  [0 0 0 0]
 ]
 [
  [1 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0]
 ]
 [
  [1 1 1 1]
  [1 1 1 1]
  [1 1 1 1]
  [1 1 1 1]
 ]
 [
  [1 1 0 0]
  [1 1 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0]
 ]
]

outputs=tf.multiply(inputs, mask)
```

**What I've tried**

I tried the naïve approach of just assigning the affected values to zero, like so:

```py
for i in range(0, len(inner_dims)):
    inputs[i, inner_dims[i]:, :] = 0
    inputs[i, :inner_dims[i], inner_dims[i]:] = 0
```

This, (as expected) gives me an item assignment error.

`TypeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object does not support item assignment`

**My question**

How can I achieve the desired masking in a fast and GPU-friendly way? Is it better to generate a mask on the fly, or can the direct assignment approach be made to work?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out a simple solution using [tf.sequence_mask](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sequence_mask) and broadcasting that solves the problem.

*However, I am not sure that pre-creating a mask like this is the most efficient way.*

```
N = 4
inner_dims = [2, 3, 1, 4, 2]

# This mask is a 5xN tensor.
seq_mask = tf.sequence_mask(inner_dims, N)

# Expand dimensions to 5x1xN, and 5xNx1, respectively.
seq_mask1 = tf.expand_dims(seq_mask, axis=1)
seq_mask2 = tf.expand_dims(seq_mask, axis=2)

# Thanks to broadcasting, the logical_and will yield a 5xNxN tensor.
mask = tf.logical_and(seq_mask1, seq_mask2)
mask = tf.cast(mask, dtype=tf.float32)

outputs=tf.multiply(inputs, mask)
```